# Анимация при наведении

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как сделать такие же кнопочки, как на этом сайте?

http://www.imagefu.com/create/button

Главная цель - анимация градиентной рамочки вокруг кнопочки.

Я полагаю, что нужно использовать какую-то анимацию и как-то вставлять градиент.
Не могли бы вы навести меня на путь к этому?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читайте про css3 transition

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0;
    transition: box-shadow 1s;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}

div:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #515151;;
}
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/tetgG/)

Comment: Ура! Спасибо за ответ!
Теперь можно идти спать)